# Why does finally and done of $animateCSS behave differently in UI Bootstrap Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, css-transitions, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap for collapsing/expanding a div section based on user clicking a button similar to the example shown in the official site - [UI Bootstrap-Collapse](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse)

I included the latest version of ui-bootstrap(0.14.2) but it was not showing the expected behavior. In particular the ***collapseDone()*** and ***expandDone()*** callbacks are never called after the $animateCSS is done the animations. (The animations are working properly, presumably because of the css transition property of the class *'collapsing'*  in twitter bootstrap.)

But when I inspected the UI Bootstrap site, I found that it's working properly as expected. (That's the class 'collapsing' is added during the animation and then removed after animation and then the class 'collapse' is added). So I checked the source code link for collapse [collapse source code -github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/collapse/collapse.js)  and found that ***finally*** is used for $animateCSS promise resolution rather than ***done*** in the ui.bootstrap.js code I included.

So could someone please explain the difference between finally and done methods of the $animateCSS function? The documentation [Angular Docs-$animateCSS][3] says that

> there is also an additional method available on the runner called .done(callbackFn). The done method works the same as .finally(callbackFn), however, it does not trigger a digest to occur. Therefore, for performance reasons, it's always best to use runner.done(callback) instead of runner.then(), runner.catch() or runner.finally() unless you really need a digest to kick off afterwards.

So it looks like both should behave similarly. Could someone shed light on this, as there seems to be very little resources to learn about $animateCSS. (google search for $animateCss returns results for animate.css which seems to be part of the earler angular js verion (v1.2) - so that doesn't help)

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to inject "**ngAnimate**" to my module. That way the animation by $animateCss was not successful, so the done() was never called. But finally will be called even if the animation is not successful.